# Show 'Google Books` items with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm studying a way to use the Google Books API.
Using this code have the expected result.

```
$page = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=julio+verne&maxResults=40");

$data = json_decode($page, true);
for($a = 0 ; $a <= 39 ; $a++) {
$img = $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'];
print '<img src="'.$img.'" alt="ScanLine"/>';
echo '<br>';
echo "Title = " . $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['title']; 
echo '<br>';
echo "Authors = " . @implode(",", $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['authors']);
echo '<br>';
echo "Editora = " . $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['publisher'];
echo '<br>';
echo "id = " . $data['items'][$a]['id'];
echo '<br>';
echo "Resumo = ";
echo "<p>" . $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['description'];
echo '</p><br>';

}
```

On the other hand, implementing and using the code form the code does not work.
My page with form have this code:

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="campos">
                        <label>
                         Search
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="search"  style="margin-right: 10px; width:250px; float:left" class="input-field" placeholder="Title, Author..."  />    
                        <input type=hidden name=numResults value="&maxResults=40">
                        <button type="submit" id="search" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

And my action have this code:

```
 $var1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
 $var2 = urlencode($_POST['search']);
 $var3 = "&maxResults=40";
 $str = str_replace(" ", "+", $var2);
 $page = $var1.$str.$var3;
 $data = json_decode($page, true);
 echo $page;
 echo '<br>';
 for($a = 0 ; $a <= 39 ; $a++) {
 $img = $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'];
 print '<img src="'.$img.'" alt="ScanLine"/>';
 echo '<br>';
 echo "Title = " . $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['title']; 
 echo '<br>';
 echo "Authors = " . @implode(",", $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['authors']);
 echo '<br>';
 echo "Editora = " . $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['publisher'];
 echo '<br>';
 echo "Resumo = ";
 echo "<p>" . $data['items'][$a]['volumeInfo']['description'];
 echo '</p><br>';
  }
```

What must be wrong?
Any advise?
Thanks from Brazil

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here? - I recommend taking the JSON response from Google (using some example parameters) and just paste the response into an online JSON editor. This will make it easier to understand and parse the response - check out this one here, it works well... http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `file_get_contents()` in the second example. So `$page` is just the url.

```
$page = file_get_contents($var1.$str.$var3);
```

Comment: Rob, Thanks. It worked the way I needed.
See Kolors, I do not need all the search results. The API documentation is clear when he explains that by default are displayed at most 10 records and 40.
These are the most relevant records to the search term.
My application is about books. Manipulate the JSON returned by the API is enough. I do not intend to use JavaScript for example to return a simple query.